# como devuelvo un array con los 5 elementos mas repetidos

Tags: javascript

Tengo una clase `Playlist` con un `array` de objetos `Song`, estoy intentando crear un método que me devuelva solo las canciones de los 5 artistas con mas canciones, pero no doy con la tecla (solo llevo un mes programando) alguien me podría dar alguna pista?

He intentado ordenarlas con sort y luego usar slice. pero no se como hacer para una vez ordenada por artistas, quedarme solo las canciones que sean de los 5 artistas con mas canciones...

Intento con `sort` pero así solo ordeno el `array` por grupo, pero no se como "cortar" para que solo me queden las de los 5 primeros, os pongo un poco de código:

```
function Playlist(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.songs = new Array();
    this.shuffled = false;
    }
function Song(title, artist, duration, score){
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.score = score; 
    this.currentSongIndex = 0;

        Playlist.prototype.orderByArtist = function(){
    this.songs.sort(function(a,b){      
        if(a.artist > b.artist){
            return -1;
        }
        else if(a.artist < b.artist){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    })
    return this.songs;
}   

Playlist.prototype.topArtist = function(){  
    this.songs.orderByArtist();
    for(let i = 0; i < this.songs.length; i++){
            let cont = 0;
            let band = this.songs[i].artist;    
                for(let j = 0, j < this.songs.length; j++)
                    if(band == this.songs[j].artist){
                        cont++;
                    }   
            checker.push(band); 
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: por favor lee el [tour]. El sitio no funciona si repetis la pregunta una y otra vez. Que fue lo que intentaste para resolver esto? y de paso, mira [ask]

Comment: gracias! ya la he editado a ver si asi es mas entendible, perdona por duplicar la pregunta pero no se bien aun como desenvolverme por aqui

Comment: lee los enlaces que te pase.. ;)

Comment: Mi recomendacion.. como recien estas empezando, no uses ni sort ni slice ni nada de eso. Hacelo a mano. Aprende a hacer tus propios algoritmos para entender el problema.. primero, cuenta las canciones por grupo... y luego ordena eso...

Comment: gracias por el consejo voy a intentar a ver si saco algo en claro!!!

Comment: he llegado hasta aqui, pero no se como guardar el numero de veces(cont) que cada artista(band) esta en el array juntos... Alguna pista? perdon por el codigo y gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0):

Los pasos que se deben realizar son:

1. Realizar un conteo de canciones por artista, para realizarlo, puedes apoyarte usando **Array.prototype.reduce()**, recorriendo cada canción de la playlist y al final creando un objeto con propiedades `{artist, songs}` donde en *artist* guardaremos el nombre del artista y en *songs* las canciones que le perteneces al artista.
2. Ordenar los artistas según la cantidad de canciones de mayor a
   menor, para esto debemos recorrer el objeto creado en el paso 1 y ordenar los artista de acuerdo a la cantidad de canciones en orden descente, aquí es donde nos es muy util el **Array.prototype.sort()**.
3. Tomar los primeros 5 artistas, aquí nos podemos apoyar de **Array.prototype.slice()**.

A continuación el método *traerArtistasPrincipales* se encargar de realizar estos pasos, simplemente le enviamos la playlist y él se encarga del resto.

Más información:

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)
- [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)
- [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)

```js
function Playlist(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.songs = new Array();
    this.shuffled = false;
}

function Song(title, artist, duration, score) {
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.score = score;
    this.currentSongIndex = 0;
}

// Método para obtener los 5 primeros artistas principales
const traerArtistasPrincipales = (playlist) => {
    let artistas_principales = [];

    if (typeof playlist === 'object') {

        // Creamos objeto donde guardamos el artista y las canciones que tiene
        const cantidad_canciones_artista = playlist.songs.reduce((artistas, cancion) => {
            if (!artistas[cancion.artist]) {
                artistas[cancion.artist] = {
                    artist: cancion.artist,
                    songs: []
                };
            }

            artistas[cancion.artist].songs.push(cancion);

            return artistas;
        }, {})

        // Ordenamos los artistas por número de canciones en orden descendente
        const artistas_ordenados = Object.values(cantidad_canciones_artista)
            .sort((song_a, song_b) => {
                if (song_a.songs.length < song_b.songs.length) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (song_a.songs.length > song_b.songs.length) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });

        // Tomar los 5 primeros
        artistas_principales = artistas_ordenados.slice(0, 5);
    }

    return artistas_principales;
};

// Prueba de ejecución
const playlist_test = new Playlist('Mi lista');

playlist_test.songs = [
    new Song('Canción 1', 'oscar', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 2', 'oscar', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 3', 'miguel', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 4', 'ana', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 5', 'oscar', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 6', 'ana', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 7', 'oscar', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 8', 'alex', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 9', 'alex', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 10', 'pedro', 1, 1),
    new Song('Canción 11', 'juan', 1, 1),
];

console.log({
    artistas_principales: traerArtistasPrincipales(playlist_test)
});
```

Comment: he llegado hasta esto:

Answer (score -1):

He conseguido llegar hasta esto:

```
Playlist.prototype.topArtist = function(){  
    let checker = [];                                   //array donde meto las bandas que ya he comprobado
    for(let i = 0; i < this.songs.length; i++){
            let cont = 0;
            let band = this.songs[i].getArtist(); 
             //-----CONDICION-----
                for(let banda of this.songs){
                    if(band == banda.getArtist()){
                        cont++;                         
                    }                       
                }
            checker.push(new Top(band, cont));          
    }
    orderByAppereances(checker);        
    temp = checker.slice(0, 5)
    return temp;        
}   
 //OUTPUT:
(5) [Top, Top, Top, Top, Top]
0: Top {band: "The kooks", appereances: 4}
1: Top {band: "The kooks", appereances: 4}
2: Top {band: "The kooks", appereances: 4}
3: Top {band: "The kooks", appereances: 4}
4: Top {band: "Nirvana", appereances: 2}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

pero no consigo que no se me repitan varias veces cada grupo, he intentado poner una condicion con .includes() e indexOf() antes del for para que si band ya esta incluida en checker no entre en ese for y por lo tanto no lo añada mas veces, pero no soy capaz....